# Combine all tuples from a list into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to combine all the tuples from a list into a string. I also need to include colon between the numbers and space between numbers and meridian. My function :

```
def create_time_list(filename):
    f = open(filename,"r")

    f.seek(0)
    fchar = f.read(1)
    if not fchar:
        raise Exception("EmptyFileError")

    f.seek(0)

    list = []

    for line in f:
        subtuple = tuple(line.split())
        for i in subtuple:
            if len(i) > 2 or len(i) < 1 :
                raise Exception("ImproperTimeError")
        if not subtuple[0].isdigit() or not subtuple[1].isdigit() or (int(subtuple[0]) > 12) or (int(subtuple[1]) > 59):
            raise Exception("ImproperTimeError")
        list.append(subtuple)
    return list
```

My list :

```
[('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]
```

Input :

```
    4 12 PM
    8 23 PM
    4 03 AM
    1 34 AM
    12 48 PM
    4 13 AM
    11 09 AM
    3 12 PM
    4 10 PM
```

How I want to output this :

```
['4:12 PM' , '8:23 PM' , '4:03 AM', '1:34 AM' , '12:48 PM' , '4:13 AM' , '11:09 AM' , '3:12 PM' , '4:10 PM']
```

Comment: Try: `lst.append("{}:{} {}".format(*subtuple))`. Note the renamed variable as you should not use the name `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
lst = [('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]

list_out = [f"{h}:{m} {abr}" for (h, m, abr) in lst]

print(list_out)
```

Result:

```
['4:12 PM', '8:23 PM', '4:03 AM', '1:34 AM', '12:48 PM', '4:13 AM', '11:09 AM', '3:12 PM', '4:10 PM']
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way is you of `map method`:

```
list_ = [('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'),
         ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'),
         ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]

print(list(map(lambda i: i[0]+':'+i[1]+' '+i[-1], list_)))
```

#### Method-2

by [@schwobaseggl][1]

in this case logic work as just `iterator over list` and using `string-formatting` add this string to newly created list will our result and that format is `{}:{} {}`

```
list_ = [('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'),
         ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'),
         ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]

lst = []
for i in list_:
    lst.append("{}:{} {}".format(*i))

# for one line list creation we can use list-comp by [@Andres Silva][1]
lst = ["{}:{} {}".format(*subtuple) for subtuple in list_]

print(lst)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['4:12 PM', '8:23 PM', '4:03 AM', '1:34 AM', '12:48 PM', '4:13 AM', '11:09 AM', '3:12 PM', '4:10 PM']
```

Comment: told me that list is not callable , I might doing some wrong to be honest, second week of python

Comment: Method 3: using list comprehension. `lst = ["{}:{} {}".format(*subtuple) for subtuple in list_] `

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi `list` is reserved keyword used for `top level function list` `list function` return list object

Comment: @denis, note that you should not use `list` as a variable, as that name is reserved. Try changing the variable `list` for some variation (eg. `list_` in the above solution), restarting your kernel, and running your code again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```py
l = [
    ('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'),
    ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'),
    ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')
]

result = [f"{hh}:{mm} {xm}" for hh, mm, xm in l]

print(result)
# ['4:12 PM', '8:23 PM', '4:03 AM', '1:34 AM', '12:48 PM', '4:13 AM', '11:09 AM', '3:12 PM', '4:10 PM']
```

List comprehensions are known to be almost always faster in python. You unpack variables from the tuple to the respective variables `hh`, `mm`, `xm` and then using those variables you create the string using f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,
x is your list

```
y = []
for timesTup in x:
    z = ':'.join((timesTup[0],timesTup[1]))
    y.append(z+' '+timesTup[-1])
```